# Trigger css background image position when hovering over parent div

Tags: css, triggers, background-image, css-transitions

I have one question, how do I trigger a background position transition of a child div by hovering hover the parent div?

I didnt find any answer at all concerning this issue, specificaly related to background positioning.

Since 3 days im trying to trigger such transition with CSS but it just doesnt work when hovering over the parent div, only the child.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

brace for some awesome pseudo code

```
parent:hover child {
    transition code;
}
```

here is a demo of what I think you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/wCHRG/

Comment: Sorry it did not work for me :( I added the transition code but nothing happened. I edited my post so you can see how I did it now.

Comment: try the fiddle, is that what you wanted?

Comment: thank you i will try it out. In worst case I will upload an example on my website of the effect just in case. Ill try out and see in fiddle if i implemented your code wrong.

Comment: I just realised, you are setting a transition to the background position, but you are not setting where you want it to transition to

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I "think" this works for what you want...
http://jsfiddle.net/wCHRG/3/